# Is there a way to load file into directory and to be able to delete it after processing

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hadoop

I am trying to save data into text file from below code and saving it to S3 bucket .

After saving I am deleting the directory from local.Below is the code i am using to save the file in newFolder.

As the file will be saved in with part file name so, renaming it to desired name.

Below code I am using :

```
enter code here
  def writeJSON(sourceDF: DataFrame, jsonConfig: Map[String, String], sqc: SQLContext, numberOfRows: String) = {
    try {
      val keyArrays = jsonConfig.keySet //to get the keys of the jsonConfig i.e. json
      val sourceJSON = sourceDF.na.fill("").toJSON
      sourceDF.show(20)
      sourceJSON.show(20)

      val jsonRowCount = sourceJSON.count
      println("JSON ROW COUNT : " + jsonRowCount)
      import sqc.implicits._
      if (rowCounter >= 1) {
        rowCounter = 1
        println("RowCounter Value : " +rowCounter)
      }
      val targetJson = sourceJSON.map(row =>
        if (rowCounter == 1) checkJSON(row, "firstrow", jsonConfig, numberOfRows).toString()
        else if (rowCounter != jsonRowCount) checkJSON(row, "middlerows", jsonConfig, numberOfRows).toString()
        else checkJSON(row, "lastRow", jsonConfig, numberOfRows).toString())
        .coalesce(1)
        .write
        .mode(SaveMode.Append)
        .text("paymentConfirmation")
         TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10)

    } catch {
      case e: Exception => throw new Exception(e.getMessage)
    }
  }
```

I am getting error on line ".text("paymentConfirmation")". Below are the error logs.

```
19/05/01 18:09:55 WARN FileUtil: Failed to delete file or dir [C:\Users\sweta.h.sharma\Documents\master_data_demo\paymentConfirmation\_temporary\0\_temporary\attempt_20190501180948_0008_m_000000_0\part-00000-33390262-54a6-4a06-8436-d807f0a49dfc-c000.txt]: it still exists.
19/05/01 18:09:55 WARN FileOutputCommitter: Could not delete file:/C:/Users/sweta.h.sharma/Documents/master_data_demo/paymentConfirmation/_temporary/0/_temporary/attempt_20190501180948_0008_m_000000_0
19/05/01 18:09:55 ERROR FileFormatWriter: Job job_20190501180948_0008 aborted.
19/05/01 18:09:55 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 8.0 (TID 8)
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:191)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:190)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: ExitCodeException exitCode=-1073741502: 
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:582)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:479)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:773)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:866)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:849)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:733)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:225)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:209)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.createOutputStreamWithMode(RawLocalFileSystem.java:307)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:296)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:328)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSOutputSummer.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:402)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:461)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:440)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:911)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:892)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:789)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.CodecStreams$.createOutputStream(CodecStreams.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.text.TextOutputWriter.<init>(TextFileFormat.scala:134)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.text.TextFileFormat$$anon$1.newInstance(TextFileFormat.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$SingleDirectoryWriteTask.newOutputWriter(FileFormatWriter.scala:305)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$SingleDirectoryWriteTask.execute(FileFormatWriter.scala:314)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:258)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:256)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1375)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:261)
    ... 8 more
19/05/01 18:09:55 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 8.0 (TID 8, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:191)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:190)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: ExitCodeException exitCode=-1073741502: 
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:582)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:479)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:773)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:866)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:849)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:733)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:225)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:209)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.createOutputStreamWithMode(RawLocalFileSystem.java:307)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:296)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:328)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSOutputSummer.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:402)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:461)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:440)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:911)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:892)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:789)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.CodecStreams$.createOutputStream(CodecStreams.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.text.TextOutputWriter.<init>(TextFileFormat.scala:134)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.text.TextFileFormat$$anon$1.newInstance(TextFileFormat.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$SingleDirectoryWriteTask.newOutputWriter(FileFormatWriter.scala:305)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$SingleDirectoryWriteTask.execute(FileFormatWriter.scala:314)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:258)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:256)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1375)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:261)
    ... 8 more

19/05/01 18:09:55 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 8.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
19/05/01 18:09:55 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 8.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
19/05/01 18:09:55 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Cancelling stage 8
19/05/01 18:09:55 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 8 (text at PaymentConfirmation.scala:114) failed in 6.882 s due to Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 8.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 8.0 (TID 8, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:191)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:190)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: ExitCodeException exitCode=-1073741502: 
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:582)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:479)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:773)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:866)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:849)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:733)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:225)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:209)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.createOutputStreamWithMode(RawLocalFileSystem.java:307)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:296)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:328)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSOutputSummer.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:402)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:461)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:440)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:911)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:892)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:789)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.CodecStreams$.createOutputStream(CodecStreams.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.text.TextOutputWriter.<init>(TextFileFormat.scala:134)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.text.TextFileFormat$$anon$1.newInstance(TextFileFormat.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$SingleDirectoryWriteTask.newOutputWriter(FileFormatWriter.scala:305)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$SingleDirectoryWriteTask.execute(FileFormatWriter.scala:314)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:258)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:256)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1375)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:261)
    ... 8 more

Driver stacktrace:
19/05/01 18:09:55 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 6 failed: text at PaymentConfirmation.scala:114, took 6.908904 s
19/05/01 18:09:55 ERROR FileFormatWriter: Aborting job null.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 8.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 8.0 (TID 8, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:191)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:190)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: ExitCodeException exitCode=-1073741502: 
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:582)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:479)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:773)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:866)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:849)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:733)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:225)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:209)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.createOutputStreamWithMode(RawLocalFileSystem.java:307)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:296)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:328)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSOutputSummer.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:402)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:461)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:440)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:911)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:892)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:789)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.CodecStreams$.createOutputStream(CodecStreams.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.text.TextOutputWriter.<init>(TextFileFormat.scala:134)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.text.TextFileFormat$$anon$1.newInstance(TextFileFormat.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$SingleDirectoryWriteTask.newOutputWriter(FileFormatWriter.scala:305)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$SingleDirectoryWriteTask.execute(FileFormatWriter.scala:314)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:258)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:256)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1375)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:261)
    ... 8 more

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1499)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1487)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1486)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1486)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1714)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1669)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1658)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:630)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2022)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply$mcV$sp(FileFormatWriter.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:173)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:173)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:173)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:145)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.writeInFileFormat(DataSource.scala:438)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.write(DataSource.scala:474)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:610)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:233)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.text(DataFrameWriter.scala:555)
    at tester.PaymentConfirmation$.writeJSON(PaymentConfirmation.scala:114)
    at tester.PaymentConfirmation$.createJson(PaymentConfirmation.scala:160)
    at utils.SitePaymentsS3Utils$$anonfun$getPaymentConfirmationCSVFromS3$1.apply(SitePaymentsS3Utils.scala:119)
    at utils.SitePaymentsS3Utils$$anonfun$getPaymentConfirmationCSVFromS3$1.apply(SitePaymentsS3Utils.scala:71)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at utils.SitePaymentsS3Utils$.getPaymentConfirmationCSVFromS3(SitePaymentsS3Utils.scala:71)
    at utils.SitePaymentsS3Utils$.main(SitePaymentsS3Utils.scala:242)
    at utils.SitePaymentsS3Utils.main(SitePaymentsS3Utils.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:191)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:190)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: ExitCodeException exitCode=-1073741502: 
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:582)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:479)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:773)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:866)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:849)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:733)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:225)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:209)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.createOutputStreamWithMode(RawLocalFileSystem.java:307)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:296)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:328)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSOutputSummer.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:402)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:461)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:440)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:911)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:892)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:789)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.CodecStreams$.createOutputStream(CodecStreams.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.text.TextOutputWriter.<init>(TextFileFormat.scala:134)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.text.TextFileFormat$$anon$1.newInstance(TextFileFormat.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$SingleDirectoryWriteTask.newOutputWriter(FileFormatWriter.scala:305)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$SingleDirectoryWriteTask.execute(FileFormatWriter.scala:314)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:258)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:256)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1375)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:261)
    ... 8 more
19/05/01 18:09:55 WARN FileUtil: Failed to delete file or dir [C:\Users\sweta.h.sharma\Documents\master_data_demo\paymentConfirmation\_temporary\0\_temporary\attempt_20190501180948_0008_m_000000_0\part-00000-33390262-54a6-4a06-8436-d807f0a49dfc-c000.txt]: it still exists.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: Job aborted.
    at utils.SitePaymentsS3Utils$.getPaymentConfirmationCSVFromS3(SitePaymentsS3Utils.scala:62)
    at utils.SitePaymentsS3Utils$.main(SitePaymentsS3Utils.scala:242)
    at utils.SitePaymentsS3Utils.main(SitePaymentsS3Utils.scala)
19/05/01 18:09:55 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
19/05/01 18:09:55 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://192.168.31.231:4040
19/05/01 18:09:55 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
19/05/01 18:09:55 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
19/05/01 18:09:55 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
19/05/01 18:09:55 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
19/05/01 18:09:55 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
19/05/01 18:09:55 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
19/05/01 18:09:55 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
19/05/01 18:09:55 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory C:\Users\sweta.h.sharma\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-0925f066-f7a3-41bf-a58c-4009dcdec115
```

I want that file should get deleted from the folder after i have save it to s3.

Comment: Do you have HDFS on local? Did you provide the entire code?

Comment: Yes . I have HFDS on my local.